# Microsoft Outlook 2010 - Custom Field to indicate whether email message is sent TO me or CCed to me

Tags: ms-office, outlook-2010

Does anyone know how to create customised fields (columns) in Microsoft Outlook 2010. I receive a lot of email and would like to define a new column in my inbox folder, where I could somehow classify email messages and show a Yes/No flag to indicate whether my email address is in the TO: list or CC: list. This would appear against each email message in the inbox view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [form region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157865.aspx) to change UI

or inject your control(s) through PInvoke like did [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27262/Additional-custom-panel-in-Microsoft-Outlook)